# Can any body help me to create this image in android by using shape

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[image]

Please suggest me which is the best way to create this image by just create png or jpeg or by using shape. I want an only bg image not "20% Off" written. I can do it by just using the circle. But I am not able to create the background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this , but it is a hack and not recommended solution . Adjust width and margin according to your requirement

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#EC8075"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
        android:rotation="-15"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]